# get the timestamp according to their events in an Object and push it into an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, timestamp

I am trying to get the timestamp of all the event types in particular objects like for in XYZ there is `open`, `processed`, `delivered` i want to get the timestamp of all the events and push it into an array for each object.

```
var data = {
  XYZ: [
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:29"
    },
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "processed",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "delievered",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:36"
    },
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "processed",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:38"
    }
  ]
};
```

my code is

```
function get_timestamps(data, event) {
  var timestamps = [];

  for (key in data) {
    var arr = data[key];
    timestamps = timestamps.concat(
      arr.filter(a => a.event == event).map(a => a.timestamp)
    );
  }
  return timestamps;
}
var openTime = get_timestamps(data, "open");
var proceesTime = get_timestamps(data, "processed");
var delieverdTime = get_timestamps(data, "delivered");
```

currently, I have got all the events timestamp separately and when I try to merge them it couldn't fulfill my requirements.

the expected output is

```
 [['open timestamp1','processed timestamp1','delivered timestamp1','open timestamp2','processed timestamp2','delivered timestamp2'],

    ['open timestamp1','processed timestamp1','delivered timestamp1','open timestamp2','processed timestamp2','delivered timestamp2']]
```

Comment: post what you already tried and we can show you how to proceed

Comment: @DovRine can you suggest something

Comment: In a couple of minutes, I'm thinking of an array.reduce idea. In the meantime, are you aware that "delivered" is misspelled in your entire data object?

Comment: this is handwritten objects so spelling is wrong.

Comment: Did you also mean to nest a duplicate of the output array?

Comment: yes, the situation is like there is an array of object for a key and in that array of objects there are different-2 events so according to that events I want to get the timestamp and it goes for other arrays of objects.

Comment: Can you give me an object with just 1 complete example? It looks like your data object is all mixed together, so I'm having a hard time understanding what your output object actually is.

Comment: I'm starting to think that what you want is to sort by timestamp, then force order by open, processed, delivered. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, but the timestamp is already sorted .i want to get all the events timestamp for all the keys and make it into an array of arrays.

Comment: @DovRine I have edited the object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably misunderstanding something, because the order output I get is different from the output you expect, in any case, this is the solution I propose

Observation.

I have not identified the cause of why when running the snippet in stackoverflow, instead of the timestamp I get `NaN`, when I test the script with node I get the timestamp values correctly. I attached screenshot of the result when running with node

[image]

```js
const data = {
  xyz: [
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:29"
    },
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "processed",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "delievered",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "delievered",
      event: "delievered",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    },
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "processed",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    }
  ],
  yyy: [
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "delivered",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:29"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "delievered",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "delivered",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:29"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "delievered",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    }
  ],
  zzz: [
    {
      email: "amar045@gmail.com",
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "delivered",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:29"
    },
    {
      office: "xyz.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "delievered",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "delivered",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:29"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "payroll",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:32"
    },
    {
      email: "amar0445@gmail.com",
      office: "yyy.in",
      reportName: "delievered",
      event: "open",
      timestamp: "02-12-2019 00:15:34"
    }
  ]
};

const object = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  const output = value.map(
    item => `${item.event} ${new Date(item.timestamp).getTime()}`
  );

  object[key] = output;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first thought at this, but I think that the output probably needs to be sorted again. I tried to keep it as close to your original code as possible so that you could understand and modify it more easily:

```
function get_timestamps(data, event) {
timestamps = []
for (key in data) {
    var arr = data[key]
    timestamps.push(arr.map(a => `${a.event} ${a.timestamp}`))
}
return timestamps
```

}

Comment: yes, the output needs to be sorted by events so I can get the output in this way ['delivered', 'open','processed']